# Form sometimes get executed, sometimes not

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which has `select` options for age and `radiobuttons` for gender. The idea is that the form can be used to search for a specific user by age and gender.

Currently, the form sometimes executes the `header` (see below) and sometimes not. So Assume, I am logged in as Conor, Conor specifies that he wants to search for a user aged between 20-21 and is male. Upon clicking submit, sometimes the form will find someone, sometimes it will not. I want the query to keep running until a user is found, unless no one exists in the database.

In this case, the header should be executed, taking the user to `messages.php` because a male aged 20 exists in the database.

Here is my approach:

**Form**:

```
 <form action="random_chat.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="age_from" id="age_from" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="age_to" id="age_to" value="50"/>
        <label for="amount">Age:</label>
        from:
        <select name="age_from" id="age_a" onchange="checkages_a()"> 
            <option value="none"></option>
            <?php
            for($i = 17; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
                echo "\t", '<option value="', $i. '">', $i, '</option>', "\n";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        to: 
        <select name="age_to" id="age_b" onchange="checkages_b()"> 
            <option value="none"></option>
            <?php
            for($i = 18; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
                echo "\t", '<option value="', $i, '">', $i, '</option>', "\n";
            }
            ?>
        </select>

        <!-- I have input type submit above the radio buttons due to table layout -->
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Click to start chat! " />

               <label for="amount">Gender:</label> 
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</input> <br />
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</input><br />
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="any">Any</input>     
</form>
```

PHP code processing the form:

```
<?php
$refined_gender = htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['gender']));
$age_from       = htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_from']));
$age_to         = htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_to']));

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // if age parameter used...
    $defined_chat = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender =? AND age BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($defined_chat, "sss", $refined_gender, $age_from, $age_to); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute ($defined_chat);

    while ($get_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($defined_chat)){
        $rand_name = $get_user['username'];
        $acc_type = $get_user['account_type'];

        if ($acc_type != "admin" ){
            // if the name genereated by db is same as logged in users name, then run query again until name is found.  
            if ($rand_name == $username){
                $defined_chat;
                } else {
                    header ("Location: /messages.php?u=$rand_name");
                }
        } else {
            echo "No user found fitting those requirements.";
        }
    } // while closed
    mysqli_stmt_close($defined_chat);   
} 
?>
```

I have tried to change the form action to '#', thinking it may be just be refreshing the page, but it didn't work.

Also, how can I make this so that even if one parameter is filled, then still execute search? For example, if I search for a male, with no age defined, it will find a male user. If I search for someone ages between 26-31 and no gender defined, then still execute header?

**Edit**:

`$username` is the session variable, which is defined at the very start of `random_chat.php`.

Comment: never ever name your submit button "submit". it can cause conflicts. try changing that first.

Comment: @Pamblam - Understood. I have changed it, still the same issue. When I submit the form, the div to the right of the page, also moves out of place.

Comment: Am I missing something, but It doesnt looks like you have `$username` defined in your code, but you are using it in a `IF` block: `if ($rand_name == $username){
`

Comment: where is your $username defined?

Comment: @andre3wap - Sorry, should have mentioned, `$username` is my session variable and is located right at the top of the page.

Comment: @Ello - `$username` is the session variable, which I have defined at the top of the page, sorry, should've specified.

Comment: ok... So my understanding is that, if my search returns 5 results, and 1 of that result's `username` is `andre` (my name), then I will not get redirected, but get this instead `$defined_chat;` ?

Comment: @andre3wap - Yes. So again, to put this into perspective, If I am logged in as Conor, say Conor is 20 years old and he searches for a user between 19-21, the database has two users who fit that bracket, Conor himself and Anderson (also 20). If the row returned has the username of `$username` (person logged in) then run the code again (`$defined_chat`) until a user is found, in this case, until Anderson is found.

Comment: So basically the backgorund is of no or little interest, you just have a problem because sometimes `$_POST['submit']` isn't set and should be, right ? Could you place a `var_dump($_POST)` the line above your test ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on the value of a submit button to determine if your form was submitted or not.  This will not work on all browsers, especially older ones, this value is not always passed back to the server, instead just look at any value inside the form to verify if submission has occurred, or the existence of $_POST in general.

Comment: Keep on truckin', TravisO ^_^

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, what you are attending to do looks to me simpler than the way you are actually trying to achieve it.

Construction you SQL query correctly may be the only thing complicated in here.
Only changing your query could actually already remove your need of the if/else for the `account_type` and the if/else to check if the current user is the same as the queried one :

```
$sql = "SELECT 
          * 
        FROM 
          users 
        WHERE 
          gender like ? AND 
          age BETWEEN ? AND ? AND 
          # with this condition you do not need to test if the user logged is the queried one
          username != ? AND 
          # and with this one, you do not care about exclude adimn either
          account_type != 'admin'
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 1";
$defined_chat = mysqli_prepare (
    $connect, $sql
);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
    $defined_chat,
    "ssss",
    $refined_gender,
    $age_from,
    $age_to,
    $username
);
```

Then about the fact that you want to be able to search even without any selection on both gender and age, you can use a combinaison of the wildcard `%` of SQL, the operator `like` and the ternary operator of PHP (you did maybe already see that I changed `gender =?` to `gender like ?` in the query above).

```
// Means if gender is different than 'any', it will assign the posted value to the variable, otherwise, it will assign the sql wildcard %
$refined_gender = (htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['gender'])) != 'any' ? htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['gender'])) : '%');
// Means if age is different than 'none', it will assign the posted value to the variable, otherwise, it will assign the lowest possible age, 0
$age_from       = (htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_from'])) != 'none' ? htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_from'])) : '0');
// Means if age is different than 'none', it will assign the posted value to the variable, otherwise, it will assign an age bigger than anyone could attain, 9999
$age_to         = (htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_to'])) != 'none' ? htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_to'])) : '9999');
```

see [ternary operators in PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)
and see [MySQL like and wildcard usage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

All in one, your processing PHP script could look like this :

```
$refined_gender = (htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['gender'])) != 'any' ? htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['gender'])) : '%');
$age_from       = (htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_from'])) != 'none' ? htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_from'])) : '0');
$age_to         = (htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_to'])) != 'none' ? htmlentities (strip_tags(@$_POST['age_to'])) : '9999');

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $sql = "SELECT 
              * 
            FROM 
              users 
            WHERE 
              gender like ? AND 
              age BETWEEN ? AND ? AND 
              # with this condition you do not need to test if the user logged is the queried one
              username != ? AND 
              # and with this one, you do not care about exclude adimn either
              account_type != 'admin'
            ORDER BY RAND() 
            LIMIT 1";
    $defined_chat = mysqli_prepare (
        $connect, $sql
    );
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
        $defined_chat,
        "ssss",
        $refined_gender,
        $age_from,
        $age_to,
        $username
    );
    mysqli_stmt_execute ($defined_chat);

    while ($get_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($defined_chat)){
        $rand_name = $get_user['username'];
        header ("Location: /messages.php?u=$rand_name");
    } // while closed
    echo "No user found fitting those requirements.";
    mysqli_stmt_close($defined_chat);
}
```

Comment: Ah, this answer came like a ray of sunshine! But unfortunately, I still get the same results. I have applied your code, and have double checked it too, but now, I cannot even search for a user. Normally, I was filter for someone aged between 20-22, and click submit, and the page will (sometimes on first click) find me a user. But it doesn't do that anymore. Even when I search for a male, and just apply that filter, it simply refreshes the page (not even the echo No user found is displayed).

Comment: Also, two things, I have very little experience in PHP, but I assumed you were missing `mysqli_stmt_execute($defined_chat);` in your code? so I added it into mine (checked with the code in and out, both still dont work). And also you have mentioned `LIKE`. Shouldn't the variable be like this in the query `'%{?}%'`? Just trying to gain some knowledge :)

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_execute($defined_chat);` is in the answer, you should read until the end. and the wildcard, is a wildcard, it match anything, that could of course be used in combinaison with something else but that is not the purpose here. Test it on your db : `select * from users where gender like '%'`

Comment: @Freddy my ternary operator assignation was acting oddly, indeed. I updated the code, so you can retry that one

Comment: - Just tried, still, neither the echo nor the header is being executed. I can't understand why, seem's like basic form processing but just keeps sending me back to the same page.

Comment: @Freddy what is in your form `action` attribute ? What is the actual name of the file holding the form and the actual name of the file holding the processing script ?

Comment: At the moment, my form's action is  `action="#"`, it use to be `action="random_chat.php"` - Both which yielded the same results. Both the form and the code processing the filters are found in `random_chat.php`.

Comment: @Freddy if you still have `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` and you changed the name of you submit input to something else than `submit` as you stated it [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551481/form-sometimes-get-executed-sometimes-not/36635167?noredirect=1#comment60704073_36551481), then that's the reason.

Comment: Ah, that was an issue! Resolved that. I think we have one barrier left, I get an `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` error on `while ($get_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($defined_chat))` - Which Im guessing is due to a error in the query itself? I have rechecked the table names and fields, all which are correct, so why the error?

Comment: Please add `echo mysqli_stmt_error($defined_chat);` right after the line `mysqli_stmt_execute ($defined_chat);` and paste the error here so we can debug

Comment: I have added the line after `mysqli_stmt_execute` (and above the while loop). Nothing seems to echo on my page? - Would you like to discuss this in chat so I can possibly provide graphics to aid with this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109255/discussion-between-freddy-and-b-enoit-be).

Answer (score 0):

You have some mixed logic, so some explanations might help.

1) header('location: ...') will tell the browser to reload the page to the new location. This does not appear to be what you want - you just want to continue execution? NOTE: You should also [nearly] always have "exit();" after a header('location: ... '); line otherwise execution continues which is [nearly] never what you want!)

2) a while loop will continue "while" the condition is true. So the loop continues while there are rows being returned.

3) Running the query again will not return anything new - you can use the same results. So just skip over until you find the result you need!

So, written in English, what you want to do after running the DB query is:

```
set a tally count to zero
while we have some rows coming from the db {
    if that row is not admin {
        if that row does not match the current user {
            show the result
            increase tally count
        }
    }
}
if tally count is zero {
    say "no entries found"
}
```

So, in code, this is

```
$foundUsers = 0;
while ($get_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($defined_chat)){
    $rand_name = $get_user['username'];
    $acc_type = $get_user['account_type'];

    if ($acc_type !== "admin" ){
        // if the name genereated by db is same as logged in users name, then run query again until name is found.  
        if ($rand_name !== $username) {
            $foundUsers = $foundUsers + 1;   // Or $foundUsers++ for short
            echo 'Matched User: ' . $rand_name . '<br>';
        }
    }
} // while closed
if ($foundUsers == 0) {
    echo "No user found fitting those requirements.";
}
```

Comment: Your 3) statement is untrue. OP have a `order by rand() limit 1` in his query

Comment: Yeah, I badly explained what I was trying to say. Updated to be correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, if you want to exclude a parameter from the query, you're going to have to build some logic to exclude that variable.

So if `$refined_gender = "any"`, then you need to exclude it from the query. I would change your combobox default values to:

```
<select name="age_from" id="age_a" onchange="checkages_a()"> 
    <option value="-1"></option>
    <?php
    for($i = 17; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
        echo "\t", '<option value="', $i. '">', $i, '</option>', "\n";
    }
    ?>
</select>
to: 
<select name="age_to" id="age_b" onchange="checkages_b()"> 
    <option value="999"></option>
    <?php
    for($i = 18; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
        echo "\t", '<option value="', $i, '">', $i, '</option>', "\n";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Then, now you've fixed the age between, to filter the gender out. Also, I've added a clause to your `WHERE` clause: `AND account_type != 'admin'`, this will filter out the admins accounts on the SQL side rather than checking on the PHP side.

```
// If gender is specified, query gender
if($refined_gender !== "any"){
    $defined_chat = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender =? AND age BETWEEN ? AND ? AND account_type != 'admin' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($defined_chat, "sii", $refined_gender, $age_from, $age_to); 
} else {
    $defined_chat = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age BETWEEN ? AND ? AND account_type != 'admin' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($defined_chat, "ii", $age_from, $age_to); 
}

mysqli_stmt_execute ($defined_chat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion #1: Possible race condition see note in code.

```
   if ($acc_type != "admin" ){
        // if the name genereated by db is same as logged in users name, then run query again until name is found.  
        if ($rand_name == $username){
            $defined_chat;<-- don't you need to re-execute this?  Seems like you are hitting a race condition since the statement result will never change

            } else {
                header ("Location: /messages.php?u=$rand_name");
            }
    } else {
        echo "No user found fitting those requirements.";
    }
```

Suggestion #2:
Outside of that you should be sure you aren't getting the current user with a 
`WHERE name NOT LIKE '%?%'` up front in the initial query and get rid of that if statement. 
Suggestion #3:
Or better, use the user IDs. What if there's another user with the same name as the searcher, but they're a different person? Base the current user match on UID, not name.
Suggestion #4:
You should absolutely almost never run a select query/statment inside a PHP (or any scripting language) loop. There's always a better way. Filter your data in the database where it's efficient. Even for inserts you can do a single bulk insert much more efficiently than a bunch of insert queries.